# HTML fixed Column widths not working correctly in MS Outlook

Tags: html, css

I have the following 2 tables.  The column widths are supposed to be fixed widths of 125px (on real table, there are more columns).
I want the columns in Table 1 to match the widths of the columns in Table 2, but when I view in an Outlook email, they do not line up.  Any suggestions?

Code below:

TABLE 1

```
‘Header Row
<table width:1000px>
<tr style=“width: 1000px;">
<td style=“width: 125px; ">
<span style=“font-size: 12px; ">Col1Title</span></td>
<td  style=“width:125px; ">
<span style=“font-size: 12px; ”>Col2Title</span></td>

‘Details
<tr >
<td style=“ height: 15px; “>
<span style=“line-height: 100%; ”> & Col1Details & </span></td>
<td style=“height: 15px;”>
<span style=“line-height: 100%; ”> & Col2Details & </span></td>
```

TABLE 2

```
‘Header Row
<table width:1000px>
<tr >
<td style=“width: 125px;“>
<span> Table2_Col1Title</span></td>
<td  style=“width: 125px;
<span> Table2_Col2Title </span></td>

‘Details
<tr >
<td style=“ height: 15px; “>
<span style=“line-height: 100%;”> & Table2_Col1Details & </span></td>
<td style=“ height: 15px;”>
<span style=“line-height: 100%; ”> & Table2_Col2Details& </span></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things here that need addressing:

1. It looks as if you're using Word to edit your HTML due to the inclusion of "smart" quotes like this: “ in your HTML. Word is probably your absolute worst choice to edit HTML in; you'd be far better off downloading something like Notepad++ or even using regular old Notepad to edit your HTML.
2. You cannot have your the width of the `<td>` tags add up to less than the width of the table; the `<td>` tags will just expand to fit the table width in unusual ways.
3. If you're trying to have two tables with one below the other, and assuming this is for an HTML email due to your question mentioning Outlook, you should wrap everything in an outer table, have a `<tr>` & `<td>` per inner table, and lay it out that way.  With HTML email you really have to throw everything you know about HTML and CSS out the window and write it old school style
4. Outlook is horrendously bad at rendering HTML email. It will probably never be perfect so don't beat yourself up over it.

That said I took a crack at your HTML, here it is below:

```
<table style="width: 1000px;">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="width: 1000px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 125px;">
                        <span style="font-size: 12px;">Table1_Col1Title</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 125px;">
                        <span style="font-size: 12px; ">Table1_Col2Title</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 15px;">
                        <span style="line-height: 100%; "> & Table1_Col1Details & </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 15px;">
                        <span style="line-height: 100%; "> & Table1_Col2Details & </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table style="width:1000px;">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 125px;">
                        <span style="font-size: 12px;">Table2_Col1Title</span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width: 125px;">
                        <span style="font-size: 12px;">Table2_Col2Title</span>
                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td style="height: 15px;">
                        <span style="line-height: 100%;"> & Table2_Col1Details & </span>
                    </td>
                    <td style="height: 15px;">
                        <span style="line-height: 100%;"> & Table2_Col2Details & </span>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Great answer - there are also online tools you can use to check your HTML specifically for Outlook (as you're right, it is notoriously bad at handling HTML emails) such as Premailer amongst others. I hate having to make Outlook friendly HTML emails.